# Use twig string variable in twig array?

Tags: twig, twig-extension

What I want to do is sth like this:

```
{% arrayData = ['hello',{{ myVar }},'is','your','coding','master'] %}
```

where the value of `myVar` is `'this'`. When I try this, it however always returns the error:

A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{"

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried removing the brackets? The variable should be available as a variable, without brackets, without quotes

Comment: What Nico said, `{{ ... }}` is purely used to output variables

Comment: Awesome, worked, cheers! There are some syntax things in twig I totally don't get tbh. Looks like I gotta check the basics again :D